# How can I fix this issue with edge values in Conway's Game of Life?

Tags: javascript, conways-game-of-life

I am trying to build Conway's Game of Life in JavaScript. The problem I am having is with edge values and undefined variables. I have several variables assigned to the squares surrounding a given square, which inevitably leads to some variables being undefined if the square is at the edge.

In the JavaScript console, it says that on line 93, it cannot read property 'style' of null. I tried to fix this issue thusly:

```
if (typeof s1n1 === null) { 
count += 0; 
} else if (s1n1.style.backgroundColor === 'rgb(0, 0, 0)') { 
count += 1; 
}
```

Basically what I am trying to do is if a variable is undefined, it skips over it and adds nothing to the count variable, and goes to the next variable. However, the way it is coded now is not working.

link: http://jsfiddle.net/stalin666/mp8kx889/

Comment: `count += 0`? Have a think about what that line does!

Answer (score 1):

That `if` block is *always* skipped, because `typeof s1n1 === null` is *always* false.

All `typeof` operations evaluate to strings, never `null`.  Specifically, the expression `typeof null` evaluates to the string `'object'`.  See the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) or search "javascript typeof" for more details.

To check for `null`, you should just use equality.  Ex, `if (s1n1 === null)`.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mp8kx889/1/) is your fiddle updated with that change.